# Using Twig how can I get the summary of the body field to use in a template?

Tags: theming, entities, 8

So I have a textarea with summary and I want to display the summary before the content.
So if I just use `{{ content.body }}` the text is displayed without the summary.

How can I get the summary ?

`{{ content.body.summary }}` doesn't seem to do the trick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your THEME.theme file you can just define it too:

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
$variables['node_teaser'] = ['#markup' => $variables['node']->body->summary];
}
```

And then display it with:

```
{{ node_teaser }}
```

Answer (score 27):

The only way I managed to solve this is:

if you only want to target the value of the summary, you can target the entity you're on. If you're on a node then you can do this :

```
node.body.summary
```

In a paragraph

```
paragraph.field_body.summary
```

You can also get the summary front content like this :

```
content.body['#object'].body.summary
```

Not great but will do for now.

Comment: That IS the only way to use the node object, because `content.body` is the render array of the body field how you configured in the view mode and if you didn't change it, it will render the full view.

Answer (score 3):

To build on what 4k4 wrote (and updated for 2018):

You first choose the way you'd like the field formatted, then you print it.

1) Go to Structure > Content Types > YOUR CONTENT TYPE > Manage Display > YOUR VIEW MODE.

2) Under the "Formatter" column, choose "Summary or Trimmed."

3) Save.

4) In your twig file you should be able to just print {{ body }} (this is what works for me, but correct me if I'm wrong and I'll update).

This works for me using the node in a View block, and should work on the node as well.

Comment: +1 This the ideal way to trim the content. In this, the site administrator can configure the trim limit as well no need of a developer help.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by simply using

```
{{ content.field_description['#items'][0].summary }}
```

wherein my description field is field_description

Comment: Perfect! it works. {{ content.body['#items'][0].summary }}

Answer (score 0):

It depend on how you have configure the body field. By default, Drupal has content.body; however, many Drupal developers avoid using it "as it comes" because its particular process may cause issues. If you go to *Structure > Content Types > YOUR CONTENT TYPE*, you can see the name of your field.
On *Structure > Content Types > YOUR CONTENT TYPE > Manage Display > YOUR VIEW MODE*, you can change how your field is rendered and add different view modes to use for specific use cases.
Finally, if you haven't been able to find a solution for your project, you could use devel or kint debug to see your project configuration and find the correct answer.